# Are there taxonomic keys for members of the family poeciliidae in America?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ichthyology, limnology

I wish to know what are the taxonomic aspects necessary for the identification of certain species of poecilids, specifically what is the role in the counting of rays and spines and also the measurements of the organism. Which documents can I guide myself from? Am looking to know the exact measurements of a specific fish, in this case *Poecilia salavatoris*.
The fish was found in Honduras, Central America in the state of Francisco Morazán in a fast-moving, shallow, seasonal brook.

[image]

The fish in question is 4.5 cm in total length and 3.5 cm in standard length.